# What's the difference between a PCAP file with a magic number of "0x4d3cb2a1" and "0xd4c3b2a1"?

Tags: endianness, pcap

I've got two PCAP files, `A` and `B`.

`A` has a 'magic number' in the header of `d4 c3 b2 a1`, `B` has a 'magic number' in the header of `4d 3c b2 a1`. According to the wireshark documentation (http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat), only `0xd4c3b2a1` and `0xa1b2c3d4` are valid magic numbers, which leads me to think that B is not a valid magic number.

Running `file` on linux backs this up, with the output of `file A` being:

```
tcpdump capture file (little-endian) - version 2.4 (Ethernet, capture length 65535)
```

`file B` simply gives:

```
data
```

It looks like that whatever wrote `B` wrote it in a 'swapped' (little-endian) format, but wrote the forst twp bytes with the nibbles the wrong way round. Given that I'd expect a big-endian system to write the whole int32 the other way around and not the individual bytes, giving a magic number of `1a 2b 3c 4d`.

Is `B` a valid file? If so, why? Can different systems write both 32-bit ints and the individual nibbles in a byte in an arbitrary order?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What's the difference between a PCAP file with a magic number of “0x4d3cb2a1” and “0xd4c3b2a1”?

A pcap file with a magic number of 0xa1b23c4d or 0x4d3cb2a1 is a pcap file in which the packet time stamps are in seconds and *nanoseconds*.

A pcap file with a magic number of 0xa1b2c3d4 or 0xd4c3b2a1 is a "regular" pcap file in which the packet time stamps are in seconds and *microseconds*.

Where did you get file B?  The only standard version of libpcap that writes files in "nanosecond-resolution" format is the version on the trunk of the libpcap Git tree, and that would only happen if the program using libpcap were reading another "nanosecond-resolution" format or explicitly requesting nanosecond-resolution time stamps from the network adapter (currently supported only on Linux, and probably requires a sufficiently recent kernel).  That's also the only version that can read them.  Wireshark won't produce them by default, although recent versions of Wireshark can read them.

Comment: Looking in wireshark, I can indeed see that it's displaying the Frame timestamp to 9dp for `B` but effectively only 6dp for `A` (last three are always 0). `B` was generated by a specialized NIC, looks like it supports ns resolution. :)

Comment: You'd either need a specialized NIC or an OS with a capture mechanism that supports nanosecond resolution to get nanosecond-resolution time stamps.  You'd *also* need a program and/or library that can get those high-resolution time stamps from the NIC/OS and that can write nanosecond-resolution time stamps; any idea what program wrote that?

Comment: Did some more digging. More than likely one of these http://www.napatech.com/products/network_adapters.html - think the drivers support writing PCAP out in 1ns resolution.